# DynamicForm validation - accept Validator_A OR Validator_B

Tags: smartclient

My DynamicForm field has 2 validators for zip code

```
[
    { type: "mask", errorMessage: "Invalid postal code", mask: "^(\\s*\\d{5}\\s*)(\\s*-?\\s*\\d{4}\\s*)?$", transformTo: "$1-$2" },
    { type: "mask", errorMessage: "Invalid postal code", mask: "^\\s*([A-Z]{1}\\d{1}[A-Z]{1})\\s*(\\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\\d{1})\\s*$", transformTo: "$1-$2" }
]
```

The first is for the United States, the 2nd is for Canada. Is It possible to set the field up to accept either option as valid input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this answer is a bit old](http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/21372-boolean-or-connect-of-validators-in-ds-xml-possible)
but I think it's still valid.